Black screen video player in Flutter android widget (Device specific)
In our own flutter package for video player, we use android media3 for android player. We are using this player widget to play video in flutter application. This works very nice with many devices. But when we force the player to change the orientation, by using full screen button, In few device like Huawei P20 lite gives the black screen. But audio and subtitles continues in the videos screen. There is not exceptions thrown by the player. This is making the problem more complex to understand.
Does any once has any clues to trace this issue and fix the issue.
Here is the package widget intergation with the flutter widget.
PlatformViewLink(
            viewType: 'video_view',
            surfaceFactory:
                (BuildContext context, PlatformViewController controller) {
              return AndroidViewSurface(
                controller: controller as AndroidViewController,
                gestureRecognizers: const <Factory<
                    OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{},
                hitTestBehavior: PlatformViewHitTestBehavior.opaque,
              );
            },
            onCreatePlatformView: (PlatformViewCreationParams params) {   
              if (androidSdkInt < 26) {
                return PlatformViewsService.initAndroidView(
                  id: params.id,
                  viewType: 'video_view',
                  layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                  creationParams: creationParams,
                  creationParamsCodec: StandardMessageCodec(),
                )
                  ..addOnPlatformViewCreatedListener(
                      params.onPlatformViewCreated)
                  ..addOnPlatformViewCreatedListener(onPlatformViewCreated)
                  ..create();
              }

              return PlatformViewsService.initExpensiveAndroidView(
                id: params.id,
                viewType: 'native_video_view',
                layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                creationParams: creationParams,
                creationParamsCodec: StandardMessageCodec(),
              )
                ..addOnPlatformViewCreatedListener(params.onPlatformViewCreated)
                ..addOnPlatformViewCreatedListener(onPlatformViewCreated)
                ..create();
            },
          )

Full screen configuration changes in flutter code:
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky)

